# What are some Foldable instances that are _not_ "general Foldable structures" in the sense of Data.Foldable?

Tags: haskell, foldable

The [documentation for `Foldable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#t:Foldable) lists several properties that are demanded of "general Foldable structures":

- For `foldr`:

  > For a general Foldable structure this should be semantically identical to,
  >
  > ```
  > foldr f z = foldr f z . toList
  > ```
- For `foldl`:

  > For a general Foldable structure this should be semantically identical to,
  >
  > ```
  > foldl f z = foldl f z . toList
  > ```
- For `foldl'` (with what looks like a typo to me):

  > For a general Foldable structure this should be semantically identical to,
  >
  > ```
  > foldl f z = foldl' f z . toList
  > ```

What are some instances of `Foldable` where these properties need not or cannot hold?

Comment: I think it should be read that these properties **do** need to hold for all well-behaved instances. Not quite sure though.

Comment: I think these properties all follow from the laws.

Comment: That `foldl` law only works for finitary structures. For an infinite snoc-list, `foldl` should be better-defined than that.

Comment: I think "For a general Foldable structure this should be semantically identical to" is just a circumlocution for "For any Foldable this should be semantically identical to", or even "This should be semantically identical to".

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I think I'll try to suggest a less amiguous wording soon.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand it, these are rules that an instance *must* obey if it defines those optional functions. By default, a `Foldable` instance only has to define either `foldMap` or `foldr`. From one of those two definitions, all the other functions of the type class follow automatically.

Often, however, type classes give you the option to define more of the type class' behaviour. This can be useful if the default, automatic definition of, say, `toList` is inefficient, and you wish to supply a more efficient implementation. This may be easier to understand for the `Monoid` type class, which defines `mconcat` as an optional function "so that an optimized version can be provided for specific types".

The laws quoted in the OP are laws that an instance must obey if you choose to define some or all of these functions yourself. As an example of a (nonsensical) type that breaks the rules, consider this `Invalid` type:

```
import Data.Foldable

data Invalid a = Invalid a deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Foldable Invalid where
  foldMap f (Invalid x) = f x
  foldr _ x _ = x -- Unlawful!!
  toList (Invalid x) = [x]
```

While it only has to define `foldMap` to be a `Foldable` instance, this one also defines `foldr` and `toList`. While the `toList` definition is fine, the `foldr` definition breaks the rules:

```
*Q53460772 Data.Monoid Data.Foldable> toList $ Invalid 42
[42]
*Q53460772 Data.Monoid Data.Foldable> foldMap Sum $ Invalid 42
Sum {getSum = 42}
*Q53460772 Data.Monoid Data.Foldable> f = \x acc -> x + acc
*Q53460772 Data.Monoid Data.Foldable> z = 0
*Q53460772 Data.Monoid Data.Foldable> (foldr f z . toList) $ Invalid 42
42
*Q53460772 Data.Monoid Data.Foldable> foldr f z $ Invalid 42
0
```

The `toList` and `foldMap` functions behave like you'd expect them to behave, but notice that `foldr f z` doesn't produce the same output as `foldr f z . toList`.

While `Invalid` is a nonsensical example, it demonstrates that you can write code that compiles and looks like it provides an instance of `Foldable`. The laws and rules associated with each function, however, makes it clear that this is not a valid instance.